# pandas python regex find all words that begin, end or contain '

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I would like to find out all words, numbers that start or end or contain '.

I tried by writing 2 regex as below. In case of the second one I added `?:` to say that text at the end of the word or at the beginning of the word is optional. But not getting required results. What did you I do wrong? I would like to find `I've, 'had, not', you're, 123'45` - basically everything that has '

```
import re
xyz="I've never 'had somebody [redacted-number] [redacted-number] [redacted-number] not. not' you're  123'45"


print (re.findall("\w+\'\w+", xyz))
print (re.findall("(?:\w+)\'(?:\w+)", xyz))

["I've", "you're", "123'45"]
["I've", "you're", "123'45"]
```

Comment: Do you consider a single `'` a word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Try this:

```
(?:\w+)?'(?:\w+)?
```

`(?:\w+)` => `?:` ensures Non capturing group, `\w+` matches word character between 1 and unlimited times. `?` ensures to match the previous token between 0 and 1 time.

https://regex101.com/r/N8Y9cQ/1

Comment: does ? outside ) make everything before ) optional?

Comment: @user2543622 `(?:\w+)?` = `\w*` - any zero or more word chars.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\w*(?!\B'\B)'\w*
\w+'\w*|'\w+
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/M5tZl3/1) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/M5tZl3/2).

*Details*

- `\w*(?!\B'\B)'\w*` - zero or more word chars, a `'` char (that is not preceded and followed with non-word chars or start/end of string), zero or more word chars
- `\w+'\w*|'\w+` - one or more word chars, `'`, zero or more word chars, OR a `'` char and then one or more word chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Jzv2Qw):

```py
import re
xyz="I've never 'had somebody [redacted-number] [redacted-number] [redacted-number] not. not' you're  123'45"
print (re.findall(r"\w*(?!\B'\B)'\w*", xyz))
# => ["I've", "'had", "not'", "you're", "123'45"]
```

In Pandas, you can use `Series.str.findall`:

```py
df['result'] = df['source'].str.findall(r"\w*(?!\B'\B)'\w*")
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to capture all **words** that contain a `'` anywhere within them, no? Try this:

```
re.findall("\w*'\w*", xyz)
```

This will find any `'` characters which are preceded or followed by 0 or more word characters. It matches all of the required words in the sample string. Your attempts used the \w+ which requires at least one word character before and after the `'`. This is why it wasn't matching `'had` and `not'`.

Upon reading other answers, I would say Wiktor's is the best. Use that.

Comment: Could you comment why this approach is better than my attempt and how it works?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).